# jQuery/quicksand/css problem in IE/Firefox (but not chrome)

Tags: jquery, css, quicksand

I'm trying to create an icon-swapping effect with jQuery+quicksand. It works swimmingly on Chrome, but on IE and Firefox, the effect doesn't work properly. Since the far-more-complicated quicksand demos all work fine in all browsers I assume  I'm doing something stupid with CSS.

Site is here: http://outsharked.com/test

When the icons animate, they stack up like a vertical list on FF and IE, whereas they should just rearrange horizontally, as they do in Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated. Containing div height is fixed; the styles for the UL are basic (and almost nonexistent in the quicksand demos) so I am not sure what could be the problem. It's almost as if it thinks the list is supposed to be a vertically-arranged list on the animation, but no such style is ever assigned as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your `Div` a fixed width, it works in Firefox.

Comment: Weird. The surrounding `div` has one, if I set the `ul` to the same width it does indeed work. Don't understand it, but it works! Thanks.